# Filter Data in Googlesheets

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-query-language, nested-if

I have to face some problem about my Googlesheets Data. I want to filter my googlesheets data between two dates and also filter more conditions at the same time in same sheets. Below are given some sample data.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1h5PW52PoMUxXtrqEmfXSCWu_OKXVO8IwUbHqcqSPRzs/edit?usp=share_link

Basically, I want to filter data between two date & two more conditions at a same time in same sheets.

Please help me about this issues.

Thanks

I am trying to hard to solve this issues but I cann't solve this with myself. so if anyone solve this issues then please do this.

I'm very glad for all of you.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use:

```
=IFERROR(QUERY('Raw Data'!A2:I, 
 "where 1=1 "&
  IF(A7="",, " and B >= date '"&TEXT(A7, "e-m-d")&"'")&
  IF(B7="",, " and B <= date '"&TEXT(B7, "e-m-d")&"'")&
  IF(A10="",," and C contains '"&A10&"'")&
  IF(A13="",," and D contains '"&A13&"'"), ), "no data found")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

> =query('Raw Data'!A2:I,"Select * Where B >= date '"&text(A7,"YYYY-MM-DD")&"' AND B<= date '"&text(B7,"YYYY-MM-DD")&"'
> AND C contains '"&A10&"' AND D contains '"&A13&"'")

Or, if you want to leave the dates empty:

> =query('Raw Data'!A2:I,"Select * Where C contains '"&A10&"' AND D contains '"&A13&"'"&if(A7="",""," AND B >= date
> '"&text(A7,"YYYY-MM-DD")&"'"&if(B7="",""," AND B<= date
> '"&text(B7,"YYYY-MM-DD")&"'")))